# splashscreen android app is crashing, doesn't goes to second activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am building small simple splash screen in which my application is crashing. I have googled it alot but unable to find answer.It first shows splash screen then is goes to second screen which is crashing.I have given time delay of 3 seconds to second screen
code is given below.

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.musically;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
    }

}
```

androidmanifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.musically">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

SplashScreen.java

```
package com.example.musically;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        new Handler().postDelayed(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Intent splashIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(splashIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }

                ,3000);
    }
}
```

activity_splash_screen

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SplashScreen"
android:background="#fff">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/logomusically"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    />


</RelativeLayout>
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

screenshot

[image]

Error

```
   Process: com.example.musically, PID: 28801
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.musically/com.example.musically.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3170)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3307)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2036)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7081)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar.setTitle(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
        at androidx.navigation.ui.ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.setTitle(ActionBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:48)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.onDestinationChanged(AbstractAppBarOnDestinationChangedListener.java:103)
        at androidx.navigation.NavController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(NavController.java:204)
        at androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(NavigationUI.java:228)
        at com.example.musically.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:26)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7258)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7249)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3150)
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @MMG  check it buddy

Comment: Add mainactivity code please

Answer (score 0):

you should check the MainActivity. the error log says that you are trying to set a non-existing ActionBar's title.

Comment: @check it buddy

Comment: @vishalnechwani please add the activity_main.xml code too.

Answer (score 0):

use DarkActionBar instead of NoActionBar

```
  <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

First of all you are using the theme as `NoActionBar` which means no actionbar used.
In that case you should call `setSupportActionBar()` with toolbar before this line

```
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
```

OR  Change the theme which has actionbar like

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```